# How should i change the listener position in web audio

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am having troubles trying to update the context.listener's position (each requestAnimationFrame) in an application using Web Audio. I have made a test environment [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmxWpp) with some variations but none of them seems to really work.

This is what i assume the correct approach is:

```
listener.positionX.value = pos.x;      
listener.positionY.value = pos.y;
listener.positionZ.value = pos.z;
```

The issue i am having is that the sound is being completely distorted, and turning the source volume down does not help. (this may very well be a bug in Chrome OSX, since i don't remember having any issues when i made something similar before, which i ran on Chrome Windows)

I also tried doing this (these 2 lines should be exactly the same btw), but that didn't help either:

```
listener.positionX.setValueAtTime(pos.x, 0); 
listener.positionX.setValueAtTime(pos.x, context.currentTime);
```

Then i tried the old and deprecated command to do this, and that sounds way better but still has slight distortion:

```
listener.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
```

The one that seems to work best is to do a linear ramp:

```
listener.positionX.linearRampToValueAtTime(pos.x, context.currentTime + 0.1);
```

But doing a new ramp on every frame is not really the correct approach, since ongoing ramps are cancelled and i think it takes the value *before* the cancelled ramp as the starting value for the new ramp. Also: when i then NOT update the value (i added that as an option in that codepen), it seems to jump back to a previous value, which leads me to think that that is maybe also the cause for the major distortion i hear when doing the ver first approach (setting the value by `positionX.value = pos.x`)

Am i doing something wrong, or am i overlooking something? How should i correctly set the listener's position on every frame?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.value` setter and `setPosition` is supposed to instantly move the listener to that position.  This will cause glitches.  (Not all browsers have implemented this behavior so some will smoothly move somehow from the old to the new position.)

A linear ramp (or other automation) is the correct way to move from one location to the next.

I didn't hear any artifacts with Chrome 71 on a macbook using the built-in speakers.  Perhaps I would if I used headphones?